# How to modify the resolution of CLOCK_MONOTONIC in Linux?

Tags: linux, resolution, clock

To get the resolution of the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` one can use the function `clock_getres` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_getres.html.

See the example provided by redhat to get the resolution of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/Using_clock_getres_to_compare_clock_resolution.html

Is there a way to change this value programmatically?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You won't get higher resolution.

Comment: I would like to get smaller rate of the clock. I am not sure why can't I change it. Is it because of the hardware or the operating system

Comment: You can reduce its resolution by truncating (integer) division.